# Django setting up database for different users

Tags: python, django, database

I have Django project for recording personal expenses and keeping personal budget.
I have created required models for the project and authorization using Django. However the idea is that each authentic user shall keep own expenses records, therefore needs likely separate database. I have researched Django documentation and it seems doest not provide answer to this. Probably there is no need to set up another database but to create unique model fields inherited from default admin user fields and store the data for each user in the single database.
Please advice correct approach for this task.

Comment: Why not just add the username/userid to each entry in the db, then you can have them all inte same table?

Comment: @olofom Thats truly great idea worth to try! But how about security? Any concerns?

Comment: Security will come down to how you implement the code. If you're just fetching the rows that match the logged in user then it should be fine.

Comment: Django will have full read/write access to the database(s) anyway. So the security must be implemented there. If you want to restrict users to only be able to access their own records, you cannot give them access to the django admin backend, because it only supports per model permission by default. You have to create a custom user interface instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always extend the auth `user` model to include additional data. You can create a new model that has all the additional fields plus a one-to-one relationship with the django `user` model.

eg:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

Here, you should be able to use the default auth user fields plus the custom fields you need.